# Instantiating abstract class in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using a plugin in Matlab for queuing network simulations, specifically plugin is Line. The is class that inherits an abstract class but does not implement its abstract method. The source is encrypted, so I cannot implement the method. Is it possible to implement the method while instantiating the class? I'm new to OOP in Matlab. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: A bit of code here would help a lot to explain what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: How come you can't just define the method that you need to define in your subclass of the abstract class?

Comment: The whole point of abstract methods is that they are defined in the subclass, it shouldn't matter that the superclass is encrypted...